# google maps api after page loading call

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I want to set up internationalization on a google place autocomplete. By selecting a language, the app should load the correct google api for that language.

For now I have this js code :

```
function loadScript(src) {
    var script = document.createElement("script");
    document.body.appendChild(script);
    script.src = src;
};

$('#' + country_id).change(function(){
            delete google.maps;
            $('script').each(function () {
                if (this.src.indexOf('googleapis.com/maps') >= 0
                    || this.src.indexOf('maps.gstatic.com') >= 0
                    || this.src.indexOf('earthbuilder.googleapis.com') >= 0) {
                        // console.log('removed', this.src);
                        $(this).remove();
                    }
            });
            loadScript("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&sensor=false&language=" + this.value);
            setTimeout(function(){ google_address(input_id, options_type, country_id, auto_complete) }, 2000);
    });
```

where google_address is the function to set up the autocomplete. this solution doesn't work and throw me the error on chrome :

```
Failed to execute 'write' on 'Document': It isn't possible to write into a document from an asynchronously-loaded external script unless it is explicitly opened.
```

also tried to use google.load but with no more success...

Any idea will be very welcome.

Comment: why the -1 ? it is unfair...

Answer (score 0):

The problem was from a document.write called by the script to load the api. This function can't be called out of page loading. Hence the error.

Thanks to [this example](http://gmaps-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/dynamicloading/scriptappend_hl.html) I made custom loaders for each language with document.body.appendChild.

I needed to delete pac-container too to unbind previous language selection.

Answer (score 0):

simply adding a callback parameter to the call will prevent from this error.

Note that `"after page loading" == "asynchronous"`